# How do I stop the close button in my modal window from scrolling with content?

Tags: html, css

The close button of my modal window is scrolling with the content. How do I stop it from scrolling.

I have provided the html and css codes below.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

If you can't provide solution but have a suggestion, please provide that, I appreciate any help.

HTML:

```
<a href="#india_snapshot" id="login_pop" class="rd-game-content-popupbutton">India Snapshot</a> 
<!-- popup of india snapshot --> 
                    <a href="#x" class="overlay" id="india_snapshot"></a>
                <div class="popup">
                    <strong>From Brad's Diary</strong>
                    <p>A developing country steeped in history, India is quite an experience. It intrigued me with its size and number of people - almost four times the population of the USA at one-third its size. And there are almost as many languages as there are states! It is a mix of tradition and modernism where serene villages co-exist with bustling metros. The people are quite friendly. From what I gathered, the society gives a lot of importance of family values.</p>
                    <p>Today, India is one of the most powerful economies in South Asia. India's economy is a mixture of village farming, modern agriculture, information technology and a wide range of manufacturing industries. Recent industrial and investment reforms have provided new opportunities for Indian business-persons and an estimated 100 million to 200 million consumers. India has a strong entrepreneurial class and a central government that recognizes the continuing need for market-oriented approaches to economic development.</p>
                    <br />
                    <strong>Key Facts and Figures</strong>
                    <br /><br />
                    Area<br />
                    3,287,590 sq Km<br /><br />

                    Population<br />
                    More than 1,200,000,000<br /><br />

                    Capital<br />
                    New Delhi<br /><br />

                    National Language<br />
                    Hindi is the national language. Apart from Hindi, there are about 24 major languages. English is an important language for national, political and commercial communication.<br /><br />

                    Religion<br />
                    All religions co-exist peacefully - Hindu, Muslim, Christian, Sikh, Buddhist, Jain and others.<br /><br />

                    Currency<br />
                    Rupees. An American dollar is approximately equal to 60 Rupees.<br /><br />

                    Natural Resources<br />
                    Coal, Iron Ore, Manganese, Mica, Bauxite, Natural Gas, Limestone etc.<br /><br />

                    Principal Crops<br />
                    Rice, Wheat, Oilseeds, Cotton, Sugarcane, Tea and Potatoes.<br /><br />

                    Major Industries<br />
                    Textiles, Chemicals, Steel, Cement, Mining, Agriculture, Automobiles and Petroleum.<br /><br />

                    Major Trading Partners<br />
                    USA, China, Japan, Germany and Iran.
                    <a class="close" href="#close"></a>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
.overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: default;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .5s;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s;
    transition: opacity .5s;
}
.overlay:target {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
.popup h2 {
    color: #07839f;
    line-height: 1.8em
}
.popup {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 50%;
    color: #666;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 40px 15px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: justify;
    top: 40%;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    width: 800px;
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.overlay:target+.popup {
    top: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
.close {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: 0px;
    width: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -ms-border-radius: 15px;
    -o-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.close:before {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    content: "X";
    font-size: 24px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
.close:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
.popup p, .popup div {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.popup label {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 180px;
}
.popup input[type="text"], .popup input[type="password"] {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px;
    background: #d8f6fd;
    border: 1px solid #66c8de;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ddd inset, 0 1px 0 #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ddd inset, 0 1px 0 #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ddd inset, 0 1px 0 #fff;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.popup input[type="text"]:hover, .popup input[type="password"]:hover {
    background: #fff
}
```

Comment: I guess you want `position: fixed` for the close button

Comment: @Huangism It didn't work.

Comment: You can't have `<a> tag` with `position:absolute` inside a `<div>` element with `position:fixed`.. well you can, but it's not going to work as expected. (`fixed` is relative to *browser window* and `absolute` to it's `parent`).  As is not a `single line modification`I suggest to remake the modal box without `fixed` property.